# append() doesn't work after previously appended contents deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I convert user input urls to bbcode and append it to the textarea, but after you delete one of the lines I appended it won't append more(but you could see the newly appended values in the firebug,really strange).Here's my code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".addUrl").click(function(){
        $("#addUrl").slideDown();
    })
    $('#su').click(function(){
        if($("#u").val().length>3)
        addUrl($("#u").val());
        $("#u").val("");
    })
    $("input[value=\"x\"]").click(function(){$("#addUrl").fadeOut();})
})
function addUrl(e)
{
    patt="http[s]*:\/\/";
    if(e.match(patt))
        u=e;
    else
        u="http://"+e;
    $("textarea[name=\"content\"]").append("\n\r[url]"+u+"[/url]\n\r");
}
```

And here's the jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/FpSsc/

Comment: Here is an improved version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/FpSsc/9/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you are changing the html inside the textarea which is the default value. It seems that as soon as you have set a new value (by typing or deleting something from the textbox) this default value is ignored.

To get round this you need to set the value of the textarea rather than append to the content:

```
function addUrl(e)
{
    patt="http[s]*:\/\/";
    if(e.match(patt))
        u=e;
    else
        u="http://"+e;

    var newVal = $("textarea[name=\"content\"]").val() + "\n\r[url]"+u+"[/url]\n\r"
    $("textarea[name=\"content\"]").val(newVal);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/FpSsc/1/

Or as Felix recommended:

```
function addUrl(e)
{
    patt="http[s]*:\/\/";
    if(e.match(patt))
        u=e;
    else
        u="http://"+e;

    $("textarea[name=\"content\"]").val(function(i, v) { return v + "\n\r[url]"+u+"[/url]\n\r"; });
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `.val()` twice, you can pass a function to `.val()`: `ele.val(function(i, v) { return v + 'new content'; });`.

Comment: @FelixKling True, that's probably the way I would do it as well but just wanted to keep it simple here. Will add to the answer

Answer (score 0):

I may advice you to use val here

```
function addUrl(e)
    {
        patt="http[s]*:\/\/";
        if(e.match(patt))
            u=e;
        else
            u="http://"+e;
        $("textarea[name=\"content\"]").val( $("textarea[name=\"content\"]").val() + "\n\r[url]"+u+"[/url]\n\r");
    }
```

please try this addUrl function.

Comment: why does my true answer get downvoted? stackoverflow didnt give me heads up of new answer while i was typing my answer.